# xpath date comparison using textbox

Tags: html, xpath, xquery

my xml file :-

```
<root>
    <name id="1">
        <region value="001">
            <date value="1989-03-09"/>
        </region>
    <name id="2">
        <region value="002">
            <date value="1989-03-09"/>
        </region>
    </name>
</root>
```

this is my code :-
i try it:-

```
function get_list() {
        var elName = $('#select').val();
           var xPath = '///date[xs:date(./@value,"-","") > xs:date("'+ elName +'")]/../@value';
            var iterator = xml.evaluate(xPath, xml.documentElement, null,
                XPathResult.UNORDERED_NODE_ITERATOR_TYPE, null);
            var thisNode = iterator.iterateNext();
            var str = '';
            while (thisNode) {
                if (str) {
                    str += ', ';
                }
                str += thisNode.textContent;
                thisNode = iterator.iterateNext();
            }
            $("#result").text(str);
        }
```

i have one textbox with `id = select`
here i want to get if `<date value="1989-03-10"/>` less-than textbox date then return there first element attribute value...
eg:-

```
input type="text"  1989-02-05 < 1989-03-10 is true then
```

o/p is:- `1, 2`
with using xpath and html is good for me and other is also
thanks

Comment: Show what have you tried

Comment: @AmGates check my update question i am add my javascript function code and xpath query update here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following query should work:

```
let $ref-date := xs:date("1989-03-10")
let $data := <root>
    <name id="1">
        <region value="001">
            <date value="1989-03-09"/>
        </region>
    </name>
    <name id="2">
        <region value="002">
            <date value="1989-03-11"/>
        </region>
    </name>
</root>
return $data/name[region/date/xs:date(@value) lt $ref-date]
```

You can try it live at http://www.zorba-xquery.com/html/demo#r0KwHwjp1weVwefDUn1Z6roVD3A=

Comment: yes its check only first step of xml whats fornext step means if i change $ref date 1989-03-15 then its not check `name id="2"` date (date value="1989-03-11"

Comment: which language is this? means php  or which?

Comment: This is done using XQuery. You can run it from PHP: http://www.zorba-xquery.com/html/entry/2011/12/27/PHP_Meets_XQuery